# How to drain a Backend Service on GCP

Tags: command-line, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I am using GCP (Loadbalancer/Backend Service/Instance Group).

What I am trying to do is to setup a process using shell script to push a canary server, before we actually roll out to production. The canary server should take a percentage (eg. 1%) of the production request, so we can spot errors before rolling out fully.

The plan is:

1. drain the canary server
2. update the canary server
3. restore the connection for the canary server

I am able to use the following command to control the capacity of the backend in GCP

```
$ gcloud compute backend-services update-backend api-canary --instance-group api-canary --global --capacity-scaler 0.01 --instance-group-zone asia-east1-a
```

However, I am not able to really drain the service by setting the capacity to 0.0

```
$ gcloud compute backend-services update-backend api-canary --instance-group api-canary --global --capacity-scaler 0.0 --instance-group-zone asia-east1-a
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.backend-services.update-backend) Could not fetch resource:
 - Invalid value for field 'resource': ''. None of the backends have a valid capacity
```

Comment: You're getting the error because at least one of the backend services must have non-zero capacity.

Comment: You are right!! After re-creating a new load balancer with at least one non-zero capacity backend, it works. Could you post this as a reply so I can mark it as an acceptable answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reposting as requested:

You're getting the error because at least one of the backend services must have non-zero capacity.

Create at least one non-zero capacity backend and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

> Set capacity-scaler to 0 if you wish to drain a backend service. Eg (as > in doc of Google Cloud):
> $ gcloud compute backend-services add-backend video-backend-service 
> --balancing-mode=UTILIZATION 
> --max-utilization=0.8 
> --capacity-scaler=0 
> --instance-group=ig-video-us 
> --instance-group-zone=us-central1-b 
> --global